# 2d Array Sort in Haskell

Tags: arrays, sorting, haskell

I'm trying to teach myself Haskell (coming from OOP languages). Having a hard time grasping the immutable variables stuff. I'm trying to sort a 2d array in row major.

In java, for example (pseudo):

```
int array[3][3] = **initialize array here

for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
   for(j = 0; j<3; j++)
      if(array[i][j] < current_low)
         current_low = array[i][j]
```

How can I implement this same sort of thing in Haskell? If I create a temp array to add the low values to after each iteration, I won't be able to add to it because it is immutable, correct? Also, Haskell doesn't have loops, right?

Here's some useful stuff I know in Haskell:

```
main = do
let a = [[10,4],[6,10],[5,2]] --assign random numbers
print (a !! 0 !! 1) --will print a[0][1] in java notation
--How can we loop through the values?
```

Comment: *Wince*. Just want to make clear that the data structure you get out of a `[]` literal is a linked list, not a contiguous block of memory. It's unsuitable for numeric work, but suitable for education yourself on how Haskell replaces loops. I am curious to see what the clever FP'ers come up with in answer to this question, but efficient array sorting is one of those tasks for which FP style just isn't very impressive. (Well, we'll wait and see)

Comment: @masonk: efficient array sorting is one of those tasks that you **never want to do yourself**, except for educational purposes. So the style that's impressive in that task is a style which allows you to re-use library functions in a general manner, without much boilerplate. A regard in which functional programming pretty much excels! — That said, sure there are applications where you do need to work efficiently with arrays. Indeed that can't be done very well in a functional style; in Haskell you'd normally side-step into a `ST`ate monad (locally), use an imperative algorithm there.

Comment: The bottom line is that there are many other times where the right answer in Haskell is to pull out an `ST` and start shuffling pointers or native value types around in an imperative style. I believe it's detrimental to the FP movement to be coy about this point. It feels like a bait and switch when you show them a fake quicksort which is useless[1] while teaching the language. When you go through K&R and read their quicksort, you are reading code that is useful in the real world. "Integrity in pedagogy", please.

[1]http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/08/quicksort-in-haskell-quicksort-is.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, well, I'll take a stab. Zach, this answer is intended to get you thinking in recursions and folds. Recursions, folds, and maps are the fundamental ways that loops are replaced in functional style. Just try to believe that in reality, the question of nested looping rarely arises naturally in functional programming. When you actually need to do it, you'll often enter a special section of code, called a monad, in which you can do destructive  writes in an imperative style. [Here's an example](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/08/quicksort-in-haskell-quicksort-is.html). But, since you asked for help with breaking out of loop thinking, I'm going to focus on that part of the answer instead. @leftaroundabout's answer is also very good and you fill in his definition of `minimum` here.

```
flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten [] = []
flatten xs = foldr (++) [] xs

squarize :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
squarize _ [] = []
squarize len xs = (take len xs) : (squarize len $ drop len xs)

crappySort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
crappySort [] = []
crappySort xs =
    let smallest = minimum xs
        rest = filter (smallest /=) xs
        count = (length xs) - (length rest)
    in
        replicate count smallest ++ crappySort rest

sortByThrees xs = squarize 3 $ crappySort $ flatten xs
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your Java code does *not* sort anything. It just finds the smallest element. And, well, there's a kind of obvious Haskell solution... guess what, the function is called `minimum`! Let's see what it does:

> GHCi> :t minimum 
>   minimum :: Ord a => [a] -> a

ok, so it takes a list of values that can be compared (hence `Ord`) and outputs a single value, namely the smallest. How do we apply this to a "2D list" (nested list)? Well, basically we need the minimum amongst all minima of the sub-lists. So we first replace the list of list with the list of minima

```
allMinima = map minimum a
```

...and then use `minimum allMinima`.

Written compactly:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let a = [[10,4],[6,10],[5,2]]   -- don't forget the indentation
   print (minimum $ map minimum a)
```

That's all!

---

Indeed "looping through values" is a very un-functional concept. We generally don't want to talk about single *steps* that need to be taken, rather think about *properties of the result* we want, and let the compiler figure out how to do it. So if we weren't allowed to use the pre-defined `minimum`, here's how to think about it:

- If we have a list and look at a single value... under what circumstances is it the correct result? Well, *if it's smaller than all other values*. And what is the smallest of the other values? Exactly, the minimum amongst them.

  ```
  minimum' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
  minimum' (x:xs)
     | x < minimum' xs  = x
  ```
- If it's not smaller, then we just use the minimum of the other values

  ```
  minimum' (x:xs)
     | x < minxs  = x
     | otherwise  = minxs
   where minxs = minimum' xs
  ```
- One more thing: if we recurse through the list this way, there will at some point be no first element left to compare with something. To prevent that, we first need the special case of a single-element list:

  ```
  minimum' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
  minimum' [x] = x      -- obviously smallest, since there's no other element.
  minimum' (x:xs)
     | x < minxs  = x
     | otherwise  = minxs
   where minxs = minimum' xs
  ```

Comment: Yeah, I know the java code wasn't doing anything. I was just trying to get the point across. I see what your example is doing. Just grabbing the minimum values of all of the lists. This is definitely helpful, but not quite what I was looking for. How can I build a list of these minimums? In order, particularly.

Comment: So you basically want `allMinima`, but sorted? How about `import Data.List` `sort $ map minimum a`?

Comment: If not, then perhaps you should properly write out what you want in imperative style.